# PHP Handle HTML link execution response

Tags: javascript, php, html

In my project, I need to execute a link in my browser to reload some events, after which my browser shows this as a success response:

```
250
```

The link looks like this:

```
http://Local_IP:port/Remote_IP/password/ReloadEvents
```

So, when I run this in my browser, it returns '250' as a success message.

Now, I need to execute that link with PHP or Javascript and pick up it's response to check if it was succesfull or not without 'visiting' that link.

I have tried running it with php's `header('Location:` and another header to return back to index.php but it doesn't work; it does return me to index page, but it is not executing my previous link.

Could it be done with PHP or Javascript?

Comment: You're looking for AJAX, but beware the Same-origin Policy. Or just send a request from PHP code.

Comment: See curl to bypass the same-origin

Comment: Any examples on this?